# Python if-else short-hand

Tags: python, python-2.7

Suppose I have some code like:

```
if A[i] > B[j]:
    x = A[i]
    i += 1
else:
    x = B[j]
    j += 1
```

Is there a simpler way to write it? Does Python offer syntax similar to this?

```
x = (A[i] > B[j]) ? A[i] : B[j]
((A[i] > B[j]) ? i : j) += 1
```

Comment: @MartijnPieters: the second part certainly is a duplicate, but I'm not sure about the first one.

Comment: @DSM: well, the first part won't be needed once more pythonic structures and loops are discovered by the OP.. Are you going to try and write a full introduction into iterators?

Comment: @DSM: I also don't see anyone below addressing that part. ;-)

Comment: @Martijn Pieters , while I am thankful for all participations, your comment is rather cheap. If you have an answer for the first part, post it. Ridicule is not reasoning.

Comment: @user1612593: I'm sorry, I don't mean to ridicule you. It takes time to get used to a new language and it's idioms. There is too little context here to give a concise and meaningful answer; you mostly do not encounter situations like yours in idiomatic Python.

Comment: @user1612593: I know MP (net-know, anyhow! :^), and he wasn't intending ridicule, he was being literal.  There's no slick syntax to do exactly what you want in Python, but that's not a problem because with with tools like `zip` and `enumerate` we don't need to.

Comment: I have edited to show that I need j and i outside of the while-loop.

Comment: @user1612593: You are basically looping over the sorted concatenation of A and B; use `for x in sorted(A + B):` for that; the [Python sort implementation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort) can handle a merge like that very efficiently. Or write a generator that takes `A` and `B` as inputs, calls `iter()` on them, and yields the smaller next value of either.

Comment: @user1612593: (Very) generic generator to do the same job: https://gist.github.com/4596098

Comment: `X if condition else Y`
If condition is true evaluate X else evaluate Y

Answer (score 374):

The most readable way is

```
x = 10 if a > b else 11
```

but you can use `and` and `or`, too:

```
x = a > b and 10 or 11
```

The "Zen of Python" says that "readability counts", though, so go for the first way.

Also, the and-or trick will fail if you put a variable instead of `10` and it evaluates to `False`.

However, if more than the assignment depends on this condition, it will be more readable to write it as you have:

```
if A[i] > B[j]:
  x = A[i]
  i += 1
else:
  x = A[j]
  j += 1
```

unless you put `i` and `j` in a container. But if you show us why you need it, it may well turn out that you don't.

Comment: Thanks. This works for the second part of my question. Up vote!

Comment: I have edited to show that I need `j` and `i` outside of the while-loop.

Comment: `x = a > b and 10 or 11` also works correctly in a specific set of problems, because anything that evaluates to false instead of `10` would make it fail, for example, a String.

Comment: `[i<2 and i or i-4 for i in range(4)]` returns: `[-4, 1, -2, -1]`. It trolled me for two days and I had to actually read code line by line with my professor to figure out why our algorithm doesn't work. Thanks.

Comment: How does this work internally: x = a > b and 10 or 11

Comment: is there a way to make it without "else"?

Comment: @Liker777 to make _what_? Short answer: you can have an `if` _statement_ without an `else` clause. But you cannot have a ternary _expression_ without the `else` part, because an expression needs to have a value in all cases.

Comment: @LevLevitsky I am not sure I understand your question "to make what". To make an if statement without else because it is shorter and more readable and cleans up the code.. Or do you mean something else? Ternary operator serves the same goal.

Comment: @Liker777 that's exactly the distinction I was trying to make. [Conditional expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) must have "else" in them.  In [`if` statements](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#if) they are optional.

Answer (score 22):

Try this:

```
x = a > b and 10 or 11
```

This is a sample of execution:

```
>>> a,b=5,7
>>> x = a > b and 10 or 11
>>> print x
11
```

Comment: `10 if a > b else 11`. No need to resort to boolean operators.

Comment: Thanks. This works for the second part of my question. Up vote!

Comment: How does this work internally: x = a > b and 10 or 11