# Does python have a shorthand to check if an object has an attribute?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, if-statement, conditional-operator

Background is I'm getting data from a JSON API where lots of fields are optional and I want most of the fields in a database. When a specific field isn't available I want an empty string (`""`) written into the database.

Currently I've been doing:

```
if jsonobject.what_i_look_for:
  dbstring = jsonobject.what_i_look_for
else:
  dbstring = ""
```

And then inserted dbstring into the database. However I'm getting a lot more of these fields now and I want a much cleaner code rather than a function which consists about 80% of if-statements.

I've found [if-shorthands](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14461984/9138821) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13710667/9138821) shorthand to check if a variable is empty, but both don't seem to work directly as a string. I've tested this using `print()` in an interactive python 3.5.2 shell:

```
>>> print(testvar or "")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'testvar' is not defined

>>> print(testvar if testvar else "")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'testvar' is not defined
```

This: `echo (isset($testvar) ? $testvar : "");` is the PHP equivalent of what I seek.

**Edit:** Since it seems relevant: The object I am trying to process is coming from Telegram's JSON API. I'm using `python-telegram-bot` as library and [this](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.chat.html) is an example object.

Comment: `jsonobject.what_i_look_for` is an attribute, not a variable. Is your question about variables or about attributes? Also, `if jsonobject.what_i_look_for:` checks whether the `what_i_look_for_attribute` is set to a truthy value; it does *not* check if that attribute *exists*. So, again, what is your question really?

Comment: Variables don't really exist in Python. There are names which are assigned objects.

Comment: [`hasattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#hasattr) is possibly what you want although it may be better to [ask forgiveness not permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12265451/ask-forgiveness-not-permission-explain)

Comment: @Aran-Fey Is there a difference in python? I've tried it with both and I get the exact same results, so I figured it wouldn't matter. If it does, I'm looking to see if a JSON object contains an attribute (can be a nested object too). Let me know if I should change my question please.

Comment: Yes, attributes and variables are different.

Comment: @confetti: what is `jsonobject`. instance of your own class? a libraries class? a dict?

Comment: If you’re looking for attributes of an object, then you can use `hasattr(obj, name)` to see if it exists, or getattr(obj, name, default)` to get the attribute if it exists or return the default if it doesn’t. But if you find yourself doing `hasattr` or `getattr` for most of your attributes, that’s often a sign that you didn’t want an object full of attributes in the first place, but a dictionary. (Notice that the stdlib json module uses dictionaries.)

Comment: I've edited my question.

Comment: @blue_note To be exact, it's https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.chat.html this (and similar) object from python-telegram-bot.

Comment: @abarnert I don't really contol the object I am getting much, I'm just processing different objects coming from telegram's JSON API using `python-telegram-bot`.

Comment: @PeterWood Mind leaving a full answer? `hasattr` or `getattr` is exactly what I needed, and it works as a shorthand too.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The *Pythonic* way is to look out for `NameError` exception that would be raised when the variable is not defined, *the name is not bound to any object* to be precise.

So, for example:

```
try:
    foobar
except NameError:
    # Do stuffs
    print('foobar is not defined')
    raise  # raise the original exception again, if you want
```

---

Names reside in namespaces e.g. local names reside in `locals()` (`dict`) namespace, global names reside in `globals()` (`dict`) namespace. You can define a function that takes name string and namespace as an argument to check for the existence, here is a hint passing namespace as a `dict` and catching `KeyError`:

```
In [1213]: def is_defined(name, namespace):
      ...:     try:
      ...:         namespace[name]
      ...:     except KeyError:
      ...:         return False
      ...:     return True
      ...: 

In [1214]: is_defined('spamegg', globals())
Out[1214]: False

In [1215]: spamegg = 10

In [1216]: is_defined('spamegg', globals())
Out[1216]: True
```

---

On the other hand, if you are looking to get the value of an atrribute string of an object, `getattr` is the way to go:

```
getattr(obj, attr)
```

For example, the following two are equivalent:

```
obj.foobar
getattr(obj, 'foobar')
```

Even you can add a default when the object attribute is missing:

```
getattr(obj, 'foobar', 'spamegg')
```

The above will output the value `obj.foobar`, if `foobar` is missing it would output `spamegg`.

You might also be interested in `hasattr` that returns `True`/`False` for an attribute existence check, instead of needing to manually handle `AttributeError`.

Comment: Is there a way I can write a function or anything for that? My goal is to get a short and clean code, having a `try` block for every variable I need to check doesn't exactly achieve that.

Comment: @confetti Names reside in namespaces e.g. local names reside in `locals()` namespace, global names reside in `globals()` namespace. You can define a function that takes namespace as an argument to check for the existence.

Comment: `except NameError` is pretty major code smell to me, unless you are in to some pretty arcane meta-programming black-magic, maybe. In any event, reading the op it isn't clear to me if this is even what they need, since they are talking about attributes on objects.

Comment: @confetti why have you found yourself in a situation where you don't know if a name is in scope or not? This doesn't seem related to your question at all, which is about attributes on objects, not whether or not variables are defined....

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I have edited my OP. I think I worded it wrong at first. I added an example of the exact object I am working with.

Comment: @heemayl This is a great answer, `getattr` was exactly what I needed though.

Comment: @confetti No worries. Added a few notes on `getattr` as well.

Comment: Thank you a lot, highly appreciated.